# Python multiprocessing pool async_apply callback not working when passing arguments

Tags: python, multiprocessing

Still somewhat of a beginner in Python. Not sure why this prints out an empty array when I am expecting an array containing five 2s

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

results = []

def func(a=1):
    if a == 1:
        return 1
    return 2

def collect_results(result):
    results.append(result)

if __name__=="__main__":

    poolObjects = []

    pool = Pool(processes=2)

    poolObjects = [pool.apply_async(func, args=(2), callback=collect_results) for i in range(5)]

    pool.close()
    pool.join()

    print results
```

But when I change the poolObjects line to this

```
poolObjects = [pool.apply_async(func, callback=collect_results) for i in range(5)]
```

It works fine and prints out an array of five 1s. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Try to change `args=(2)` to `args=(2,)` (note the comma). `(2)` is exactly the same as just `2`, *the comma creates tuples*!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is in how you're passing the argument:  `args` has to be a tuple (or sequence).  So change

```
... args=(2) ...
```

to

```
... args=(2,) ...
```

The trailing comma creates a tuple of length one, containing the integer 2.

Then your program will print

```
[2, 2, 2, 2, 2]
```

So why didn't you get an error?  You did ;-) - but it was suppressed.  The error doesn't occur in the main program, but in the background machinery that arranges to send work across process boundaries.  There's simply no good way to report such errors, so they're suppressed.

In the case of `apply_async`, the error is saved away, waiting for you to apply `.get()` to the result object.

So, e.g., add this loop to the end of your original program:

```
for f in poolObjects:
    f.get()
```

Then the suppressed error will be reported, like so:

```
TypeError: func() argument after * must be a sequence, not int
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the additional information on getting the error!! The original code that I had contains multiple params and it was actually failing for some other reason (now that I can see the error :)). The sample code that I wrote is failing because of the missing , but I thought the reason was the same.

Comment: I have a puzzle here, when there are 2 or more args, looks like the comma is not needed. I mean, "args=(i)" is not correct, while "args=(i,j)" is correct. I am not sure, could you explain a little bit here?

Comment: @Memories, but you do have comma, between `i` and `j`. It's the comma that makes a tuple, not the parentheses.  As the value of a keyword argument, the parenthesis are needed too only because a comma has a very different meaning too in argument lists:`args=i, j` would be viewed instead as two arguments. In other contexts, not so; e.g., as statements `a = i,` and a = i, j` both create tuples.

Comment: @TimPeters, Yeah, sorry for not clear. I mean there is no need of a comma at the end of j. For example, I define a function f(x,a), I will parallel x, then what should I set args of the apply_async, should I write "args = (x, a)" or args = "(x,a,)"?

Comment: @Memories, it doesn't matter. They're two ways of spelling the same 2-tuple. Almost everyone would do it `(x, a)`, though.  When there's only 1 element, the "trailing" comma is necessary, because plain old `(x)` denotes the same object as plain old `x`. The comma is necessary then to say "I mean a 1-tuple containing `x`".